# Islam Self-Evaluation -- Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :D

**Note:** This eval will be closing on **27 September 2012**. Get your votes in!

Comment: I don't understand -- why are we voting on questions that the community already voted on, again, in a meta post? And clarify please that votes are on "the whole question" (including answers) or just the text of the question.

Comment: @ashes999: The idea is to look at the big picture and judge if the question and it's answers make the internet a better place for finding out about Islam.  The idea is to take a step back and evaluate the whole page as if you just found it via Google.  On other self-evaluations I found myself downvoting (on meta) a question I'd upvoted on the main site.

Comment: @ashes999 (and anyone else who might be interested): I don't feel qualified to judge _any_ of these questions, so I'm not voting.  But I might comment on one or two things that I see.

Comment: @ashes999 I couldn't have said it any better than Jon did. :)

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I truly appreciate it. :D

Answer (score 9):

[Is keeping a lost property lawful?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/is-keeping-a-lost-property-lawful)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I found this question and answer utterly fascinating.  Looking around, this answer seems better than what you might find on other sites too.

Comment: Good question because of being a practical question that is really useful to many people. And good answer for being well-referenced.

Comment: The question was very important and practical one

Answer (score 8):

[What exactly is the difference of meaning between saddan and suddan in Qur'an verse 36:9?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/saddan-vs-suddan-surah-yasin)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Great question, produced solid answers.

Comment: I agree with you, it is a good question.

Comment: I could remember my feelings when (after researching) I found that answer, I was very pleasant that Ashes999 asked that question and made me get that knowledge, quite a good question (and answer, indeed :D ).

Answer (score 4):

[Is predicting the future haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/is-prediction-haram-in-islam)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Sounds like the OP had a basic misunderstanding of the issue and the answers set it straight.  It's natural to have these sorts of trivial questions, but it seems like this sample turned up a fair number.  The answers look good to me, however.

Comment: The is a usual must-have question in the site as it's important for every Muslim. If the answers were good (as they're now) then it would reflect a good-quality content of the site.

Comment: Agreed with @JonEricson. Yes, the answer was a good one.

Answer (score 4):

[Traveler's Salat: When the reduction should be started?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/travelers-salat-when-the-reduction-should-be-started)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The posted answer is good, but this is an issue in which there is scholarly disagreement; a single answer from a single school feels lacking.

Comment: I agree, I think it could use more answers.

Answer (score 4):

[Is it permissible to start the fast while in the state of janabah (sexual impurity) and then perform Ghusl later on?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/start-the-fast-while-in-a-state-of-janabah-sexual-impurity-and-then-perform-gh)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I think this is a fair, it has some great answers.

Comment: I'm not either way on this one...

Comment: -1: The question is effectively a one-liner, and while the answers are *correct*, I wouldn't really say they're *good*.  Were this the first (or only) post a new user saw, I doubt it would give a good impression of the site as a whole.

Comment: Well I'm confused about this, it's a tricky answer and good to know its content for muslims, but also would be trivial from the view of non-Muslims, the only one I didn't know how to vote (up/down).

Comment: It's a basic question, but good because it would be embarrassing to ask someone in person. The answers are well-cited, straight to the point too.

Answer (score 1):

[Does God cause natural disasters?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2150/how-does-islam-view-natural-disasters)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The question seems to pop up a lot in religious sites.  This version is a bit sparse and from the comments it seems the OP wasn't satisfied with the answers.  But NesreenA's answer seems well-supported.  I like Marc Gravell's comment too, but it's not an answer for the site.  ;-)  The -7 answer probably should be deleted.  Sounds like Ansari's comment could be the seed for an alternate or supplemental answer too.

Comment: This question should be interesting for both Muslims and non-Muslims, it's good to have/see it in our site, IMO.

Comment: It's a good question, but I've seen a few similar ones appear in the past few months.

Answer (score -1):

[Are the English translations of the Qur'an practical to read with the purpose of understanding?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/english-quran-translations)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Mr.TAMER is probably correct that this is a duplicate.  As an outsider, I find this to be an important question to have answered well.  [Wikipedia's answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quran_translations#Islamic_theology) is very helpful to me.  The answers here... not so much.  Part of the problem is that they are too chatty.  The question has problems too, since it's not clear what's being asked.

Comment: -1 because the content is not that good. The general idea of the question is good and a must-have in our site.

Comment: It's a good question, but the answers for that one aren't so good, as compared to the answer on the question linked as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

[The Change of Qiblah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/the-change-of-qiblah)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Seems like the possible duplicate is _much_ better and the answers would work for the original question too.  Would it make sense to close this one in favor of the other?

Comment: Good question, I'm surprised it's not answered yet! As an outsider I would be interested in it and if there were good answers it would reflect a good-quality content of the site. The possible duplicate answer includes the time/place information but they aren't really required in the duplicate question, while they're required in the original question. But for sure it's not duplicate as it asks *Why* the qiblah was changed.

Comment: I would like to see more practical question on the site. Though the question was an important one.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate, just worded differently.

Answer (score -1):

[Is it permissible to underline translations of Qur'an in the mushaf?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/underline-translations-tafseer-of-holy-quran)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Probably should be closed as a dup of [Is it ok to take notes on mushaf?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1704/138)

Comment: -1 I don't think such a question is useful, it's too easy and reflects a low-quality content of the site.

Comment: It's a good, valid question, but someone else asked it first.

Answer (score -1):

[What is the opening Du'aa of salat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2243/duaa-to-say-when-i-start-my-salat)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: "Please answer quickly..." is not a good sign.  The question could stand some editing by someone who understands it.

Comment: Now the question is OK, although probably not interesting for non-muslims, but could be for Muslims. But it's fair and reflects good quality IMO (+1).

Comment: Agreed with @TamerShlash +1

Comment: It's a very basic question that most Muslims know the answer to. The answers are high quality, but that's because it's really easy to find an answer to it.